# I want to use bootstrap class and next.js modules together inline

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js

[image: next js modules and bootstrap classes]
I want to use bootstrap classes and my definitons in next.js modules together. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

First, rename your `.header-top` to `.headerTop`  in `header.module.scss`.

Then, include your class name:

```html
<div className={`${styles.headerTop} container d-flex ...`}>
```

---

**Explanation**: class names in [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) are automatically processed to make them unique to ensure scoping. For example, `.headerTop` will become something like `.header_headerTop__JnCx9` (`.fileName_className_randomString`). Therefore, in components you need to include your class names as JavaScript expressions rather than strings. Namely, if you would have one class name, you would do: `<div className={styles.headerTop}></div>`. But in your case you want to include your own class name with bootstrap classes (which are not CSS modules). One way of doing it is using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allow to include expressions within strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first install bootstrap.

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

You can only import css in one location in NextJS.

create pages/_app.js and import the css file.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

in pages/_app.js

Head Tag and insert ALL bootstrap into it:

```
  <Head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </Head>
```

Then in any component, once you have imported your Name.module.css, e.g.:

import styles from '../styles/Navbar.module.css';

Now you can combine self-made CSS classes with Bootstrap classes like this:

```
<div className={`${styles.redBorder} bg-dark`}></div>
```

NOTE: you CAN NOT use dashes for class names, so this will NOT work:

.red-border;

this will NOT apply in next.js

instead use CamelCase.

.redBorder;

then it works.